# SharePoint Document Library 404 Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

**Help-**

Any idea what would cause sharepoint's doc library's tree view navigation to break?

**What-**

We have a sharepoint site that uses the template Document Center to hold all of our docs.  In the master page of the site there is a site hierarchy showing a tree view for all the folders in the document library.  When clicking on the folders from the tree view we get a 404 error but navigating to the folder from the document viewer webpart on the child page works fine.

**When-**

The issue started yesterday when my boss was playing around w/ the appearance of the document library web part's Chrome type trying to add a link to the top to get better breadcrumb navigation when using the folder links in the webpart.

**Example:**

1. Clicking on the root folder of the document library named "Documents" goes to this url w/ a 404 Error:

   http://portal.domain.net/firmdocs/Documents
2. Go here we get a listing of the items:

   http://portal.domain.net/firmdocs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

**What did I try**

1. We didn't change the name of the doc library recently
2. I am going to do an IIS reset tonight
3. Tried changing the chrome type back to what it was w/ no luck.
4. Checked the master page and child page back up versions from a few months ago and no luck.  Also the current fiels have not been edited anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you modify any of the views for the DocLibray? It could be a link to an invalid view.

Comment: Nope, we are just using the one "All documents" view.  Good idea to check though!

Comment: Okay I didn't think my boss did but you are right.  He deleted all the views!  I was able to see the items because the webpart saves it's own view but after I created a view "All documents" it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the original ListViewWebPart in the view is tampered with in some way.

Check to make sure your boss hadn't accidentally closed the original ListViewWebPart in AllItems.aspx

To do that, navigate to http://portal.domain.net/firmdocs/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?contents=1 (the ?contents=1 is the important part)

You should see only **one** ListViewWebPart in that list.

The other thing you can try is opening AllItems.aspx in SharePoint designer. Make any change to the page (insert a space in the markup, for example) and save it, clicking yes on the prompt to customize a page from the site definition. Once it's saved, right click on it and "Revert to Site Definition."

Comment: I only see one ListViewWebPart in the list and trying to do th Revert for the AllItems didn't work either.  Both really good ideas.  Any thing else to look for?